# #'and is an invalid function?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to see if all the values in a list are truthy. For some reason, `(apply #'and lst)` errors with:

> Invalid function: and

This also happens when I try `(cl-reduce #'and lst)`.

However, `(apply #'max lst)` seems to work fine.

Right now, I'm using `` (eval `(and ,@lst)) ``, but that feels ugly.

Comment: `and` is a special form rather than a function.

Comment: You should use a function with the desired behaviour, such as `(cl-every 'identity lst)` or `(-all? 'identity lst)`.

Comment: @wasama thanks. I'll do that instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really is only a partial answer (since I can't say why or really provide a workaround for it beyond what you already have).

As per `C-h f and`

> and is a special form in `C source code'.
>
> (and CONDITIONS...)
>
> Eval args until one of them yields nil, then return nil. The remaining
>   args are not evalled at all. If no arg yields nil, return the last
>   arg's value.
>
> [back]

So even though it behaves like a function it isn't one.  The same error gets generated by using a `macro` in the place of `and`.

Comment: It doesn't behave like a function : that it stops evaluating arguments once one of them is nil. `(and nil (drop 'bomb))` is safe as long as `and` is not a function.

Answer (score 3):

To add to and summarize what others have said:

```el
(functionp 'and) ; ===> nil
```

End of story.

From the Elisp manual, node [What Is a Function](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/What-Is-a-Function.html):

> You can use the function `functionp` to test if an object is a
>   function:
>
> -- Function: functionp object
>        This function returns `t` if OBJECT is any kind of function, i.e.,
>        can be passed to `funcall`.  Note that `functionp` returns `t` for
>        symbols that are function names, and returns ‘nil’ for special
>        forms.

---

(Man, I hate the new curly-quoting in the manuals.  Makes me replace each of them with `` ` `` after pasting from the manual here. Twice as much effort as when the manual (sanely) used `` `...' `` instead of `‘...’`.)

Answer (score 1):

**What is a function?**

To understand why this happens, we need to know what is a function. When evaluating the lisp form `(myfunc arg1 arg2 ...)`, emacs first checks what `myfunc` is. If it is a function, emacs evaluates all lisp forms `arg1`, `arg2`, etc. then calls the function `myfunc` with the resulting lisp objects as arguments.

As was noted, `and` is not a function, it is a special form, thus it can evaluate its arguments as needed. As I gave in a comment earlier, the form `(and nil (drop 'bomb))` is safe because `(drop 'bomb)` is never evaluated.

On the other hand, `(apply #'and (list nil (drop 'bomb)))` is not safe, because `apply` *is* a function, so emacs first evaluates `#'and` (the result is a symbol), then evaluates `(list nil (drop 'bomb))`, which is again a function call, so you guess what happens next : `nil` is evaluated, then `(drop 'bomb)` is evaluated.

**Why does `apply` complain ?**

Trying to use `apply` on a special form (or a macro) doesn't make sense, because the special form can't possibly have its special behaviour, so it throws an error.